# How do I upload a .csv to stack overflow?

Tags: discussion

I am having trouble executing a Dunn test in R: it simply continues to load without ever finishing. I get neither results, nor an error message.

I want to upload the csv file here to make this problem reproducible (since I wonder if the issue could be file size), but I can't figure out how to upload a dataset to SO. Is it possible? Thanks,

Comment: No. You cannot upload data to SO. See [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for other ways to try to make your problem reproducible.

Comment: If you think the issue is file size first step *before* asking on SO is to try it with a smaller file!!!

Answer (score 5):

Users here typically provide a minimum working example, which usually means some subset of the data...